# Rails many nested if

Tags: ruby, if-statement

In my controller, a lot of nested if

```
@cat = params[:categ]
@gid = get_uid(params[:url])
if @gid
    @data = get_task_info(@gid,@cat)
        if @data
        task = Task.new_task(@cat, @data, params[:qty], current_user.id)
            if task.uniq?
                if current_user.pay_for_task(task)
                task.save
                else
                @error = 3 
                end
            else
            @error = 4 
            end
        else
        @error = 2 
        end
else
    @error = 1
end
```

Advise me how to write this code is more correct?

Comment: Is this a question, request, or an order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the least you could do is to indent your Ruby code properly. Please try a little more humility when asking questions here - we are not your servants.

This may help you. It isn't the most efficient it could be, but error handling isn't really a place where you need the best performance!

```
class LibraryError < RuntimeError; end

begin

  @cat = params[:categ]
  @gid = get_uid(params[:url])
  raise LibraryError, 1 unless @gid

  @data = get_task_info(@gid, @cat)
  raise LibraryError, 2 unless @data

  task = Task.new_task(@cat, @data, params[:qty], current_user.id)
  raise LibraryError, 4 unless task.uniq?

  paid = current_user.pay_for_task(task)
  raise LibraryError, 3 unless paid

  task.save

rescue LibraryError => err

  @error = err.message.to_i

end
```

But it would be nicer if the error messages were informational strings instead of just numbers. (Despite appearances the numbers are *stored* as strings, which is why I had to write `to_i` when assigning to `@error`.)

Comment: Thank you. I do not quite understand about the servants. I only asked for advice on how to do better.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it this way:

```
def create
@cat = params[:categ]
@gid = get_uid(params[:url])
return @error=1 unless @gid
@data = get_task_info(@gid,@cat)
return @error=2 unless @data
task = Task.new_task(@cat, @data, params[:qty],current_user.id)
return @error=4 unless task.uniq?
return @error=3 unless current_user.pay_for_task(task)
task.save
end
```

Thank you all for the help